# jQuery Validator - Dynamic Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Adding a validator to my form:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('whatever', function(val, el) {
// whatever goes here
}, 'A maximum of ' + $('#my_id_here').val() + ' categories can be selected.');
```

This doesn't fly.  I always get undefined.  Is this a good, simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{    

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateCountries", function(value, element) {

                    alert('s'); 

                return this.optional(element) || /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(value);
            }); 

    // add the validation rule   
    $("#form1").validate();    

    $("#lbCountries").rules("add", { validateCountries:true });   

});
```

Inside the Add method you can perform your validation!

**UPDATE 1:**

With dynamic text you will loose the error messages displayed. Here is a way to tackle that issue:

```
// add the validation rule   
    $("#form1").validate(    

    {   
       messages: { lbCountries: "please specify the countries" } 
    }

    );
```

The lbCountries is a ListBox control.

**UPDATE 2:**

You can attach another rule attribute with the rule as shown below:

```
  $("#lbCountries").rules("add", { validateCountries:true, noOfSelectedItems:3 });
```

Now, you can check for the rule when the event is fired:

```
$("#lbCountries").rules().noOfSelectedItems; // this will return 3
```

Comment: But what if I had a list of checkboxes and I wanted to make sure that only 4 were checked, but that value can't be hardcoded?  I need a way to make it sometimes say "Only <x> checkboxes can be selected.".

Comment: You can do a hack (not nice) by having a custom property on the checkbox like only = 4. Now, when you access the checkbox list you can find out how many checkboxes needs to be set and you can validate that!

Comment: The validation itself isn't the problem, I can just use a hidden for that.  The specific part I'm having trouble with is making the *message* itself tailored to the number I'm looking for.

Comment: A better approach will be to extend the jQuery validation and add a new selector for noOfItemsSelected. Then you can make sure when you add a custom rule the noOfItemsSelected is always met!